# VBA MSXML - Prevent inserting namespace URI into Xpath query result

Tags: xml, vba, kml, msxml

I am trying to return **verbatim** text from an MSXML2 node. The XML in question is a KML file with the following structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>data.kml</name>
    <Folder>
        <name>Temporary Places</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
            <LookAt>
                <gx:TimeStamp><when>2000</when>
</gx:TimeStamp>
                <longitude>-107.105195493537</longitude>
                <latitude>40.11614841516315</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.0484794930795848</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>209596.4338269165</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>-107.105195493537,40.11614841516316,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I run an XPath query to grab the 'Document' element....

```
Set xNode = .selectSingleNode("//ns:kml/ns:Document")
StrXML = xNode.xml
```

This is the value of StrXML...

```
 <Document>
    <name>data.kml</name>
    <Folder>
        <name>Temporary Places</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
            <LookAt>
                <gx:TimeStamp **xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"**><when>2000</when>
</gx:TimeStamp>
                <longitude>-107.105195493537</longitude>
                <latitude>40.11614841516315</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.0484794930795848</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>209596.4338269165</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder **xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"**>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>-107.105195493537,40.11614841516316,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
```

The XML that is returned now has the GX namespace URI, which is not present in the raw file. I simply want the XML without that namespace being inserted into the tag. Is this possible with MSXML2?

Comment: In rules of XML, you cannot have a namespace prefix like `gx` without its definition. In original doc, this root tag contained this URI. To comply as XML, your parsed version moved the URI to the tag the prefix is used.

Comment: You are having issues because there is a default namespace : `xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"`  All the tags do not have a prefix because there is no name associated with the default namespace

Comment: @Parfait I realize this. I am wondering if possible to have MSXML provide original XML without inserting URI

Comment: No. You will need to *change* original XML since you cannot use the `gx` namespace prefix without its URI definition and adhere to XML rules.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language to transform XML files. Specifically, parse out the `Document` tag and remove all underlying namespaces with local name (i.e., without prefix or URI). With MSXML, you can run XSLT 1.0 scripts:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file which is a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:k="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="k:kml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="k:Document"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93YNgWx/1)</kbd>

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLT()
    ' REFERENCE Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim StrXML As String

    ' LOAD XML AND XSLT 
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM XML TO NEW DOCUMENT
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    StrXML = newDoc.xml

    Set newDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set xmlDoc = Nothing         
End Sub
```